# Texstudio - Preview no longer jumps to text where cursor is at

Tags: texstudio, preview, live-preview

Yesterday I accidentally hit the escape button instead of the backward quote (`) button, causing my preview to close. I reopened it by pressing `f7` but whenever I build & view now using the `F1` button, the preview no longer jumps to the text my cursor is at.

Does anyone know how to fix this? As I never adapt settings, everything is still the same as far as I know. In any case my PdfLaTeX is set to `pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` and I use the Internet PDF Viewer (Embedded).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: See here: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRBjyyyFUZ-RMmhkimwB1SheTT-5p95wt1VbSsk7wOoS5BMCu7C note that there are two buttons (below the LINT word). They are used to follow cursor and so on. Check how you are using them.

Comment: That picture is incredibly small

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer. Below the preview you have to lock icons. The first on says `cursor follows scrolling` and the second one says `scrolling follows cursor`. Make sure that the second one is enabled and the preview will jump again!

Comment: Yes, that are the buttons I told you. Sorry, I found that screenshot on Google.